# Passing variables between actions after AJAX call in Zend Framework

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework

I have an ajax call that I'm making to the controller which should update the number of articles shown on the page. I've created an action in the controller which handles the ajax request. See here:

```
public function articleswitchAction(){
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $tileLayout = $this->_request->getParam('tc');

    $landscape = 14;
    $portrait = 16;
        if ($tileLayout == "portrait"){
            $limit = $portrait;
        }elseif ($tileLayout == "landscape"){
            $limit = $landscape;
        }else{
            $limit = 15;
        }
    }
```

The $limit variable is set in another action within the same controller and this variable sets the initial View.

What do I need to do to update the view after I've changed the variable with my AJAX call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use AJAX, you can change your HTML contents only with javascript. AJAX call to this action would return something like

```
15
```

You need to take this value and set it to element where the count is shown.

For example:

```
$.get(
    'url/to/action',
    {'tc':'landscape'},
    function(returned_data) {
        $('#articleCount').text(returned_data);
    }
);
```

Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I just have that return in place to make sure ajax is updating the variable. I'll remove that from my post, it might be a bit confusing.

Comment: I think I misunderstand your question or you misunderstand, how PHP works. Live cycle of all variables are request-based. If you don't return anything from your action, it does not matter how you chance the $limit variable - it's just a local variable.

Comment: So i'm not able to make it a global variable?

Comment: Global variable is still request-based. You could use it in other methods, other classes etc., but magic won't happen to your HTML code - it's already sent to the browser. If you need to keep track of some application data, you have to use files, database or something like that. But this is not the case here. If you need to update HTML by ajax, use javascript similar to that in the answer.

Comment: so I have an action that generates the article page, should I have my AJAX call update that action instead of creating a separate action just for the AJAX request?? And then make a seperate javascript at the view level for the same article action??

Comment: You cannot "update action" :) Action is just a method, which returns some value. On first request, your action returns page HTML code. Then AJAX called action could return only needed information. You can reuse the same action if you want, just checking if it's AJAX request.